# Where got I get weblogic portal framework codes?

Tags: weblogic

There seems to be some weblogic framework codes, how do I download it for use with my weblogic portal project?

```
framework/features
framework/markup
framework/scripts
framework/skeletons
framework/skins
```

Answer (score 0):

you can copy some code from the framework folder into your project by using the "Merged View" in OEPE. Therefore you have to open the "Portal Perspective" and then select on the left side the Tab "Merged". Navigate to the folder you are interested in and select "Copy to Project" via the context menu.

Cheers,
Tobias